# Changing custom fields after a certain amount of time wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. **I have an Image for which links need to be changed after a certain amount of time**

Like here is an image on website in the morning **8AM to 12PM it redirects the users to abc.com** when any user clicks.
In the meantime **between 12PM to 6PM it redirects the users to def.com**.
Etc.

Could anyone have any idea how to achieve this?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify your theme where the image is and make a 'if' condition based on current time.

eg

```
if(date('G') < 12) 
{
   echo '<a href="abc.com"><img src="image.png"></a>';
} else {
   echo '<a href="def.com"><img src="image.png"></a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much CGeorges